# Putting parentheses around this PHP expression changes the result. Why?

Tags: php, logic, operators

These two lines produce different results:

```
$r1= true xor true ;
$r2=(true xor true);

var_dump($r1);
var_dump($r2);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Why?

Codepen example: http://codepad.org/O4Kn1YVa

Comment: there's only one logical conclusion....

Comment: The `=` operator has a higher [precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) than the `xor` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

= is higher priority than xor

```
$r1 = true xor true ;
```

=>

```
($r1 = true) xor true ; // "=" has highest priority
```

=>

```
$r1 xor true ; // and only now xor
```

In this case you do not write result of xor anywhere and have lost it.

In case with result 2 you are forcing the execution order by parentheses.

Comment: You are probably right. Still it feels somewhat unexpected. I simplified the example a bit now. Maybe you want to adapt your answer too.

Comment: Done. Also you can get same behavior in case string concatenation and ternary operator "?:" when use it with out parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

All parentheses do is to enforce the precedence. So if adding them makes a difference, you've changed the precedence / execution order.

Which is the case here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Thank you. that is making more sense in order to clear the confusion.